# how to save an image file in a SQL table?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

```
CREATE TABLE ImageTable
(
    Id int,
    Name varchar(50) ,
    Photo varbinary(max) 
)
```

i am using oracle 10g
unable to create table 
error: missing right parenthesis

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Been a while since I dealt with Oracle, but if my memory serves me right Oracle do not use the `varbinary` type but you can use `blob` or `long raw` instead, so the statement would be something like:

```
CREATE TABLE ImageTable
(
  Id int,
  Name varchar(50) ,
  Photo blob 
);
```

Comment: but can u help me how to give this blob type an image file to save into the table

Comment: @user2839878 I'm afraid I don't remember Oracle well enough, but take a look at the first answer on [this page](http://www.club-oracle.com/forums/insert-images-into-oracle-database-t664/) which was among the first that I found with Google. I hope it helps :)